# Python won't generate a random number because x is not defined but it is

Tags: python

I am trying to build a small game in python. The idea is that there will be a random generated number and before you start you can choose your difficulty (the max number the random number will be) and I ran into a problem.

I have defined `difficulty_input` where it asks you what the difficulty should be and saves it to a string called `difficulty`. After this, I defined `difficulty_check` where it checks in what category the answear fits in (easy, medium or hard) and after it found what difficulty it is, it generetes the random number according to the difficulty but I get an error syaing:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
from random import randrange

global x
def difficulty_input():
    global difficulty
    difficulty = input('Choose the difficulty;Easy(1-20 ), Medium(1-50 ), Hard(1-100): ')

def difficulty_check():
    difficulty_input()
    if difficulty == "Easy":
        x = randrange(20)
    elif difficulty == "Normal":
        x = randrange(50)
    elif difficulty == "Hard":
        x = randrange(100)
    else:
        difficulty_check

difficulty_check()
print (x)
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but I'll just note: you are abusing globals; there is no reason to use them here. Each function should return the data that it produces. The first function should return `difficulty` instead of assigning to a global variable, and the second function should return `x`.

Comment: the statement `global x`, put in the global scope, makes no sense. The point of the `global` keyword is to notify a **function** that `x` should be taken from the global scope, and not its local one

Comment: You had a false belief about what the `global` statement does; I am interested to learn how people come to have these sorts of false beliefs so that I can design languages that are easier to understand. Can you say a little about what you thought that `global x` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to `global x` inside the function. Everything outside - in the main program body - is by definition `global`:

```py
#import random
from random import randrange

x=0
def difficulty_input():
    global difficulty
    difficulty=input('Choose the difficulty;Easy(1-20 ),Medium(1-50 ),Hard(1-100): ')

def difficulty_check():
    difficulty_input()
    global x
    if difficulty=="Easy":
        x = randrange(20)
    elif difficulty=="Normal":
        x = randrange(50)
    elif difficulty=="Hard":
        x = randrange(100)
    else:
        difficulty_check

difficulty_check()

print (x)
```